# how to get HTML content with HTML tags from LWC tags

Tags: javascript, lightning-web-components, html, lightning-datatable

Is it possible to get HTML with tags from the lwc components?

Can I get something like (in my JS)

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>SomeHeading</th>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SomeVal1</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>SomeVal2</td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

from `<lightning-datatable ....>`

I tried

1. `this.template.querySelector('lightning-datatable');` but it returns
    `[object HTMLElement]`
2. if I try to add .toString() to it then it returns `SecureElement: [object HTMLElement]{ key: {"namespace":"c"} }`
3. Adding .data with JSON.stringify returns the JSON which was passed to the lightning-datatable
4. while adding .value gives undefined

In none of the above case I could retrieve the actual HTML. So how can can I get the HTML content preferably in a string format from any lighting component, especially in my case from lightning-datatable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In short, you can't get the full html contents in  because of Shadow DOM in LWC.
To understand more about shadow dom, read [here](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/component-library/documentation/en/lwc/lwc.create_dom)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. So, Can you please let me know what exactly is returned by this.template.querySelector(), also what all methods are available for LWC in querySelector for LWC?
Also, to drill down, what is the command to make [object HTMLElement] in human readable format?

Comment: Aura does not use Shadow DOM. Only LWC does.